# PHP Switch statements Error

Tags: php, switch-statement

I made a site and I added a pm thing and when I go to pm.php it gives me a error:

> Fatal error: Switch statements may only contain one default clause in /home/vol10_3/HIDDEN.com/HIDDEN/htdocs/includes/classes/pm.class.php on line 673

Code:

```
    function get_new_messages($uid=NULL,$type='pm')
    {
        if(!$uid)
            $uid = userid();
        global $db;
        switch($type)
        {
            case 'pm':
            default:
            {
                $count = $db->count(tbl($this->tbl),"message_id"," message_to LIKE '%#$uid#%' AND message_box='in' AND message_type='pm' AND    message_status='unread'");

            }
            break;

            case 'notification':
            default:
            {
                $count = $db->count(tbl($this->tbl),"message_id"," message_to LIKE '%#$uid#%' AND message_box='in' AND message_type='notification' AND message_status='unread'");
            }
            break;
        }

        if($count>0)
            return $count;
        else
            return "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as the error states. Go over the manual if you haven't already http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error message is completely self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually use the brackets or default like that.

```
<?php

switch ($type) {
    case 'pm':
        // Do something when $type is 'pm'
        // This can be multiple statements
        break;

    case 'notification':
        // Do something when $type is 'notification'
        // This can be multiple statements
        break;

    default:
       // Do something else
       break;
}
```

You only add default once, for the code that will execute if none of the other cases are executed. The "case: 'pm':" section is starting a block that will go until the break statement exits it. If there is no break statement it will enter the next block (in this case notification).

Here's a link to [PHP's website](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) that has some more examples and details about how those statements work.